# Как сделать цикл с ожидающим ответом?

Tags: python, python-3.x, сокет

Начал только изучать Python (Мой первый язык), и никак не могу понять как мне сделать цикл с ожидающим ответом. Я делаю клиент с подключение к совету и хочу ему с помощью цикла например отправить 100 текстовых сообщений "Ping", но не чтобы он отправлял пачкой 100 сообщений, а при отправке одного сообщения ждал ответ от сервера. Как это можно реализовать?

На данный момент я смог только реализовать цикл на бесконечный обмен сообщениями (Не без помощи гугла).

```
import socket

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.connect(('localhost', 9193))
request = None

try:
    while request != 'quit':
        request = input('Mess: ')
        if request:
            sock.send(request.encode('utf8'))
            response = sock.recv(255).decode('utf8')
            print('Answer: ' + response)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    sock.close()
```

[image: Текущая реализация]

Comment: Пожалуйста, добавьте свой код в вопрос в текстовом виде, а не в виде картинки.

Comment: Давно делал подобное: https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/tree/80720b22abf86d0f88c15751a8a230f48df5473c/socket__tcp__examples/send_recv__commands

Comment: А есть более простая реализация? Мне пока сложно понять предложенный механизм. Не хочу просто копипастить, а желаю разобраться в подобном механизме.

Comment: Вы уже используете блокирующий метод `sock.recv(255)` - это значит, что ваш код будет ждать, пока не получит указанное количество байт (255) в ответ от сервера (разумеется, если не возникнет иных исключений в честь ошибки). Поэтому вам нужно всего лишь обернуть свой код (блок с `try/except`) в цикл, убрав внутренний `while`.